# cannot map this.props(value comes up as undefined or empty array)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, express, react-redux

I have set up react/redux so that when component mounts, it will render the information. When I console log this.props.heroes.data, I get a value of `[{id:1,heroname:'Batman',realname:'Bruce Wayne'},{id:2,heroname:'Nightwing',realname:'Richard Grayson'}]`. When i try to map `this.props.hero.data`, I get an `undefined` statement and the `console.log` turns into an empty array.

My stack is React,Redux,Express,PostgreSQL

I tried playing around with this.props.heroes did some console logs and was able to go from undefined completely to undefined with an empty array.

My heroes component page:

```
class AllHeroes extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.getHeroes();
  }
  render() {
    const heroes = this.props.heroes;
    console.log("heroesreal", heroes);
    console.log(typeof heroes);
    if (!this.props.heroes) return "LOADING";
    else {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Placeholder</h1>
          {heroes.data.map(hero => {
            return <div key={hero.id}>{hero.heroname}</div>;
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ heroes: state.heroes });
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getHeroes: () => dispatch(getHeroes())
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AllHeroes);
```

My redux for heroes:

```
const GOT_HEROES = "GOT_HEROES";

const gotHeroes = heroes => ({ type: GOT_HEROES, heroes });

export const getHeroes = () => async dispatch => {
  const { data } = await axios.get("/api/heroes");
  dispatch(gotHeroes(data));
};

const heroesReducer = (heroes = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GOT_HEROES:
      return action.heroes;
    case DELETE_HERO:
      const heroId = action.id;
      return heroes.filter(hero => hero.id !== heroId);
    default:
      return heroes;
  }
};

const combinedReducers = combineReducers({
  heroes: heroesReducer,
  villains: villainsReducer,
  hero: heroReducer
  // villain: villainReducer
});
```

I don't believe i have any store connectivity issue as I had an error for that before and i fixed it by putting a provider and store in my very top component.

Expected page to render: `Batman Nightwing` but got `undefined: []`. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you post your full console logs?

Answer (score -1):

Your reducer should look like this

```
const GOT_HEROES = "GOT_HEROES";

const gotHeroes = heroes => ({ type: GOT_HEROES, heroes });

export const getHeroes = () => async dispatch => {
  const { data } = await axios.get("/api/heroes");
  dispatch(gotHeroes(data));
};

const state = {
    heroes: []
}
const heroesReducer = (heroes = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GOT_HEROES:
      return { heroes: action.heroes , ...state };
    case DELETE_HERO:
      const heroId = action.id;
      const { heroes } = state
      newHeroes = heroes.filter(hero => hero.id !== heroId);
      return { heroes: newHeroes, ...state }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const combinedReducers = combineReducers({
  heroes: heroesReducer,
  villains: villainsReducer,
  hero: heroReducer
  // villain: villainReducer
});
```

Thats how you can add more data in single reducer as well
Plz refer these 
https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/refactoring-reducer-example

Comment: Hi! I tried to use that but now my console logs come up as undefined as now it is an empty array

Comment: yes initially it would be an empty array because we initialise it as empty check your GOT_HEROES case does it has new heroes list or not